# How to perform update(PUT) call in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, crud

I am new to angularjs.

I have following UI template **DashBoard.html**
[image]

on click of **CREATE NEW EVENTS** i am posting data to server.

In the screen shot above **=>** is **EDIT** functionality.

On click of that pencil symbol I am displaying below UI template.
**Manage-CMS.html**
[image]

Now I want to fill those empty text boxes with the pre-filled value.

and also onclick of SAVE button I want to update that data to server.

How could I achieve that ?

Please help.

CODE I am trying:

```
codeApp.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http) {

    $scope.username = "Admin";

    $scope.apps = [];

    $scope.initController = function(){

        var appDetails = new Array();
        var appObject = new Object();
        $scope.id = sessionStorage.id;

        $http.get('http://192.168.1.30:8090/apps/').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);

                for(var key in data._embedded.apps){
                    appObject = data._embedded.apps[key];
                    appDetails.push(appObject);
                    $rootScope.appId = data._embedded.apps[key].appId;
                }
                $scope.appDetails = appDetails;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Failed to load app details");
            });
    };

    $scope.go = function (path) {
        $location.path(path);
        var display = false;
        if(!display){

        }
    };

   $scope.addApp = function(){      
        $scope.apps.push({'name':$scope.name, 'domain': $scope.domain, 'appId' : $scope.appId, 'secret' : $scope.secret});
        // Writing it to the server
        //      
        var dataObj = {
                name : $scope.name,
                domain : $scope.domain,
                appId : $scope.appId,
                secret : $scope.secret
        };  
        var res = $http.post('http://192.168.1.30:8090/apps/', dataObj);
        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = data;
        });
        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });     
        // Making the fields empty
        //
       $scope.name='';
       $scope.domain='';
       $scope.appId = '';
       $scope.secret = '';
    };

});
```

NOTE: same SAVE button is used for both server side functionality i.e. POST and PUT

Comment: Please show what have you tried\implemented? The question is too generic and there can be multiple approaches.

Comment: @Chandermani please see the code I have added.

Comment: What exactly is your question? $http has a put() method that works the same way as post(). So use it when you want to put instead of post.

Comment: @JB Basically I need to display already filled values in that textbox when I click on edit. So how to do that ?

Comment: You send a GET request to get the data to display, and store this data in the scope, where the view expects to find them.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data of that row on click of the edit button, the easiest way to do this is to use a modal ( I prefer using bootstrap based angular-bootstrap by angular-ui https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap ).
Pass the data of your ng-repeat row to the modal and then update the data in the form. On save you can call $http.put/post to update the data to the server.

Comment: I am passing my data to that row on click of the edit button but how to utilize it in HTML to display those values in textbox from my passed data.

Comment: You can use your data as resolve variables if you use angular-ui bootstrap modal. The example on their page is quite explanatory. Once you have the variables in scope you can use it how ever you want in the view.